# Can you recommend a hosted Document (Content) Managing Service?

Tags: document-management, cloud-hosting

We've migrated our issue tracking system and source control to hosted fogbugz (called fogbugz on-demand), and it's so much nicer because we don't have to worry about hardware, connectivity, backup etc.

Given this, we are thinking to migrate our document management software (currently using Alfresco on our own server) to hosting service as well.

However, my search didn't result in good candidates. We are thinking about getting an Amazon EC2 instance and deploy an Alfresco installation by ourselves, but we'd prefer a service if it'll come out of the box.

We like Alfresco, but it doesn't have to be Alfresco.. Do you guys have any recommendations? Thanks.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." Reference: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alfresco.com` itself lists three [hosting partners](http://www.alfresco.com/partners/hosting/) -- not necessarily a recommendation, I guess, but have you explored how those partners' offerings and prices suit (or don't suit) your specific requirements?  Maybe if you do such exploration and communicate what different needs you have compared to those offerings, any advice you receive can be made more precise.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't even notice that.. Will give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

it's true that alfresco.com has listed 3 hosting providers but they are quite expensive in terms of pricing, i have hosted some of my applications on a Virtual server but later switched over to a US based company call Real time data services which provides Workgroup Servers for [quickbooks hosting](http://www.myrealdata.com). they are very cost effective and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look [OpenERP](http://www.openerp.com), maybe you'll find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are some great answers here, but here's a few more questions that you may want to ask:

1. What are your security requirements for the documents?  Putting "sensitive" documents onto an external server may expose you to legal action.
2. Why are you outsourcing?  Often, outsourcing increases your total costs (which could be bad), but it lowers your HR costs (which may be good).  Also, outsourcing may costs the same as insourcing, but you can spread out your hardware investment over time.  Your boss may be much happier with speding $1000 / month for 3 years instead of spending $24000 this month and $300 / month over the next 3 years.
3. How much control do you need over your system?  Should you be able to do anything and everything, or are you happy with the administrator's web interface?  If this application is considered "business-critical", then it makes the most sense to have 100% control over the Alfresco instances **and** the hosted server.  However, if this application does not generate revenue, you have a lot more options.
4. Finally, how much time do you have to devote to the "conversion"?  It would be great if these sorts of tasks could be completed in a couple of hours, but often they require weeks of setup work and dozens of hours of unexpected maintenance.  Make sure that the people who are sponsoring this conversion are aware of the potential costs.

Hope that helps!